# Should I use CONTAINS or CONTAIN?

Tags: word-choice

An example of a miniature Sudoku puzzle is:

[image]

Notice that it consists of four rows, four columns, and four 2 x 2 boxes.

I was thinking of using the following wording for the instructions:

> Fill each empty square with a number so that every row, every column, and every 2 x 2 box contains all the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 each exactly once.

I am uncertain whether my instructions should use the word CONTAINS or CONTAIN.  Which is better and why?  Any other help in improving the instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: Boil your question down further, to what the number of every is, and you should find duplicates

Comment: _Each_ and _every_ are singular, while _all_ is plural. _Any_ can swing either way.

Comment: @Unrelated I don’t understand your comment.

Comment: ELU is not a grammar checking service. You may want to try [ell.se] or just put this in the editor of your choice which may or may not give a squiggly line underneath. To start you off, what is the subject that goes with the verb 'contain(s)'. Is it 'box' or 'numbers'?   That should be enough for you to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: I'm going with Fill all squares so that each row, column, and 2x2 box **contains** the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 once.

Comment: I don't share @YosefBaskin opinion because the subject of the verb is row+column+box, giving the plural "*contain*" for the verb.

Comment: I streamlined the whole sentence to set up the singular with *each*.